# How do you specify additional jars for the mr job launched from hive jdbc queries?

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, avro

I am trying to query a hive table via jdbc that uses avro storage format but I am getting a class not found error in the mr job spawned by the query. The strange thing is that I can run the query from hive shell without the exception occurring.

I can run a query that does not spawn a map reduce job (`select * from table limit 10`) and it works fine.

```
2014-03-12 10:23:34,040 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:165)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:160)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:330)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/mapred/FsInput
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroGenericRecordReader.<init>(AvroGenericRecordReader.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat.getRecordReader(AvroContainerInputFormat.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:65)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avro.mapred.FsInput
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably [`hive.aux.jars.path`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration): *The location of the plugin jars that contain implementations of user defined functions and serdes*. The CLI can pick up another config value from your JDBC hiverserver/hiverservre2. Try running `set hive.aux.jars.path;` in the two environments and compare the results. Eg. [here](http://dennyglee.com/2013/03/12/using-avro-with-hdinsight-on-azure-at-343-industries/) Denny adds all avro JARs to hive.aux.jars.path in hive-site.xml.

Comment: The aux jars are configured and picked up when running hive queries via the hive shell or oozie workflows, the problem is only happening when making a jdbc query that spwans a map/reduce job.

Comment: I had the same issue when executing a Hive query from the hive command line. The solution of Remus above + restarting the hive console solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to execute the following sql stmt for each new connection created.

```
add jar /hive-ext/avro-mapred-1.7.5-cdh5.0.0-beta-2-hadoop2.jar ;
```

The path `/hive-ext` is local to the hive server ie on the same machine that is running the hive server

Be sure to change your statement to match the name of your `avro-mapred` jar file